# Is it true that the spectral radius is always less or equal to any matrix norm?

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

The *spectral radius* of a matrix is the max eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}$ of it.*Matrix norm* is a kind of norm satisfying some axioms.

**For any matrix A,is it true that $\lambda_{max}\le \Vert A\Vert$ for any matrix norm on A?**

It is easy to do with specially induced matrix norms ,which are induced from vector norms.When a matrix norm is induced by a vector norm,what we need to do is to notice the consistence of the matrix norm and the vector norm.

But what's about the others?**What's about the matrix norms which can not be induced by vector norms,such as the Frobenius norm?**(The *Frobenius norm* is defind by $\Vert A \Vert =\sqrt{trac(A^TA)}$.You can consider the $I_n$ to find that this kind of norm can't be induced by any vector norms.)

A proof or a counterexample is expected for this question.

Thank you.

Comment: If $\Vert . \Vert$ is a norm, then the same is true of $\lambda \Vert . \Vert$ for every $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The spectral radius is bounded above by all *submultiplicative* matrix norms (including but not limited to induced norms).

Comment: @user1551 May i ask for a proof?I fail to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone has pointed out in a comment, if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, then so is $c\|\cdot\|$ for any $c>0$. So, given any $A$, we will have $\rho(A)>c\|A\|$ when $c$ is sufficiently small. The answer to your question is therefore negative.

It is true, however, that $\rho(A)\le\|A\|$ provided that $\|\cdot\|$ is a *submultiplicative* matrix norm (i.e., a norm such that $\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$ for any $A$ and $B$). Let $\lambda$ be the largest-sized eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Pick any nonzero vector $y$. As $\|\cdot\|$ is submultiplicative, we have
$$
\rho(A)\|xy^T\|=|\lambda|\|xy^T\|=\|Axy^T\|\le\|A\|\|xy^T\|.
$$
Since $xy^T$ is a nonzero matrix, $\|xy^T\|>0$. Therefore $\rho(A)\le\|A\|$.